# Can an electromagnetic wave's interference with an electric circuit increase current?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Radio antennas work on this principle but it is based on frequency resonance,does resonance matters and can e.m waves create current in a d.c circuit.

Comment: Yes, it is the same thing, but is usually called EMI, electromagnetic interference.

Comment: Yes but it would be an AC current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps better asked in engineering SE?

All circuits are radio antennas.   They will receive an alternating current, but usually it will be an off-resonance effect, and therefore small.   Most electronic products have circuits on the scale of centimeters, so they might resonate with EM waves of 4X longer frequency (roughly 10cm.)   The AC effects will become significant for centimeter waves:  cell towers and microwave oven leakage.  There may also be DC effects, if the induced radio-frequency signals exceed about one-half volt, which turns on the diode junctions inside transistors.

In Berlin, gardeners were keeping their plants alive by hanging fluorescent lamps above, which would be lit up capacitively by nearby cell towers (or perhaps lit by the city FM stations in VHF band.)  It takes RF e-fields of kilovolt/meter to light an unconnected fluorescent tube.  The transmitter-owners complained about the lost wattage, and the authorities banned this inventive vegetable-growing technique!

Comment: So if the no of photons interfering at an instant is increased,then current increases right?

Comment: Also can you tell me how this process happens and how  to accomplish it?

Comment: @Anns yes right, if the rest of the circuit isn't changing or turning (rotating,) then the # of photons is proportional to watts.  Increase the power density of the incoming EM waves, and currents in the circuit will increase as the square-root.  Four times the power gives 2X the induced amperes, ohms being constant.

Comment: @Anns to demonstrate this, just walk too close to a microwave transmitter and it might damage your iphone circuitry, while an AM 1MHz transmitter of the same wattage won't do much.  The microwave (centimeter-waves) strongly excite the cm-length copper conductors.   Also try this: place an old CDROM in a microwave oven for about 5 seconds, standing it upright somehow, for viewing. Currents of many amperes appear in the metal foil, and "electromigration" fractures spread across.  The tips of the fractures are vaporized by the "compressed" currents diverted around the tips.